# PYQT5 Graphic Area Not Updating When Button Clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I am painting some squares and a circle on in a graphics scene and I would like to connect those squares with multiple lines that will start at the circle and branch out like a tree. When the user clicks the button in the lower left corner the lines should draw in the scene. Once the lines are drawn in the scene the user should be able to zoom into the lines and select the lines just like you can with the circle and squares.

The path is determined by a function called `group`. This function will take the points and make a `graph` structure for an outline of how the points are supposed to be connected. I know this can be better and I would like it to be better, but I didn't want to ask too many questions in this post. As an example, the output should look something like

```
{0: [1, 5, 6], 1: [7], 7: [12], 5: [4]}
```

This means point `0` is connected to points `1`,`5`and `6` and point `1` is connected to point `7` and so on.

Then I have a `class` called `PathLine` that should set all of the attributes for changing colors when it is selected and whatever else I would like the user to be able to see in the future.

When the user clicks the button it will run a function in my `Viewer` class called `drawConnectingLines` this is where I wanted it to draw the lines. I can tell the function is running and I am not getting any errors, but nothing is showing up in the window.

I have tried adding `QApplication.processEvents()`, `self.update()`, and `self.scene().update()`, but nothing seems to make a difference. Also If I try to draw the lines on the load of the program it will not draw anything. Not even the points.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
rom PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from math import sqrt,cos,acos,asin,degrees,pi,hypot


class LogObject(QObject):
    hovered = pyqtSignal()
    notHovered = pyqtSignal()

def create_square():
    scale = 250
    path = QPainterPath()
    path.addRect(-0.076,-0.07,0.1520,0.1400)
    tr = QTransform()
    tr.scale(scale, scale)
    path = tr.map(path)
    return path

def create_circle():
    scale = 250
    path = QPainterPath()
    path.addEllipse(QPointF(0,0), 0.0750, 0.0750) # Using QPointF will center it

    tr = QTransform()
    tr.scale(scale, scale)
    path = tr.map(path)
    return path

def drawPath(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    scale = 250
    path = QPainterPath()
    path.moveTo(x1,y1)
    path.lineTo(x2,y2)
    tr = QTransform()
    tr.scale(scale, scale)
    path = tr.map(path)
    return path

class PathLine(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self,x1,y1,x2,y2):
        super(PathLine,self).__init__()
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        # self.name = name
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable,True)
        self.setScale(1.5)
        self.setPath(drawPath(x1,y1,x2,y2))
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.log = LogObject()
        self.setPos(x1, y1)
        self.isSelected = False

    def findLineWidth(self,zoomValue): # This function is for creating the line width value of all the drawn Objects
        if zoomValue > 18:
            zoomValue = 18
        lineWidthF = -0.0000177256625115696*(zoomValue)**4 + 0.000440875172476041*(zoomValue)**3 + 0.00941580772740735*(zoomValue)**2 - 0.370069940941448*(zoomValue) + 3
        self.updateLineWidth(lineWidthF)

    def updateLineWidth(self,lineWidth):
        pen = self.pen()
        pen.setWidthF(lineWidth)
        self.setPen(pen)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemSelectedChange:
            color = QColor(Qt.green) if value else QColor(Qt.white)
            pen = self.pen()
            pen.setColor(color)
            self.setPen(pen)
        return QGraphicsItem.itemChange(self, change, value)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        color = QColor("red")
        pen = self.pen()
        pen.setColor(color)
        self.setPen(pen)
        self.log.hovered.emit()
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        color = QColor(Qt.green) if self.isSelected else QColor(Qt.white)
        pen = self.pen()
        pen.setColor(color)
        self.setPen(pen)
        self.log.notHovered.emit()
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)


class Point(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, r, name):
        super(Point, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.name = name
        if self.name.split('__')[1] == '0':
            self.setPath(create_circle())
        else:
            self.setPath(create_square())
        self.setScale(1.5)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
        self.setRotation(180+self.r)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.log = LogObject()
        self.setPos(x, y)
        self.isSelected = False

        pen = QPen(Qt.white)
        pen.setStyle(Qt.SolidLine)
        pen.setWidthF(3)
        self.setPen(pen)

    def findLineWidth(self,zoomValue): # This function is for creating the line width value of all the drawn Objects
        if zoomValue > 18:
            zoomValue = 18
        lineWidthF = -0.0000177256625115696*(zoomValue)**4 + 0.000440875172476041*(zoomValue)**3 + 0.00941580772740735*(zoomValue)**2 - 0.370069940941448*(zoomValue) + 3
        self.updateLineWidth(lineWidthF)

    def updateLineWidth(self,lineWidth):
        pen = self.pen()
        pen.setWidthF(lineWidth)
        self.setPen(pen)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemSelectedChange:
            color = QColor(Qt.green) if value else QColor(Qt.white)
            pen = self.pen()
            pen.setColor(color)
            self.setPen(pen)
        return QGraphicsItem.itemChange(self, change, value)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        color = QColor("red")
        pen = self.pen()
        pen.setColor(color)
        self.setPen(pen)
        self.log.hovered.emit()
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        color = QColor(Qt.green) if self.isSelected else QColor(Qt.white)
        pen = self.pen()
        pen.setColor(color)
        self.setPen(pen)
        self.log.notHovered.emit()
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self,event):
        print(self.name)

class Viewer(QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.origin = QPoint()
        self.changeRubberBand = False
        self.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.area = float()
        self.setPoints()
        self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.reset_fit)
        self.selectedItems = []
        self.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.black)


    def setItems(self):
        self.data = {
            "x": [
                -2415594.9965,
                -2414943.8686,
                -2417160.6592,
                # -2417160.6592,
                -2417856.1783,
                -2417054.7618,
                -2416009.9966,
                -2416012.5232,
                # -2418160.8952,
                -2418160.8952,
                # -2416012.5232,
                # -2417094.7694,
                -2417094.7694,
            ],
            "y": [
                10453172.2426,
                10454269.7008,
                10454147.2672,
                # 10454147.2672,
                10453285.2456,
                10452556.8132,
                10453240.2808,
                10455255.8752,
                # 10455183.1912,
                10455183.1912,
                # 10455255.8752,
                # 10456212.5959,
                10456212.5959,
            ],
            "rotation":[
            0,
            313.9962,
            43.9962,
            # 223.9962,
            227.7070,
            227.7070,
            313.9962,
            43.9962,
            # 43.9962,
            223.9962,
            # 223.9962,
            # 43.9962,
            223.9962,
            ]
        }

        self.adjustedPoints = {}
        for i, (x, y,r) in enumerate(zip(self.data["x"], self.data["y"],self.data["rotation"])):
            p = Point(x, y,r, "Point__" + str(i))
            p.log.hovered.connect(self.hoverChange)
            p.log.notHovered.connect(self.notHoverChange)
            self.scene().addItem(p)
            self.adjustedPoints[i] = [x,y]
            # if i == 0:
            #     self.adjustedPoints['c__'+str(i)] = [x,y]
            # else:
            #     self.adjustedPoints['s__'+str(i)] = [x,y]

    def drawConnectingLines(self):
        # result = self.group(self.adjustedPoints, 'c__0')
        result = self.group(self.adjustedPoints, 0)
        for startPoint in result.items():
            x1 = self.adjustedPoints[startPoint[0]][0]
            y1 = self.adjustedPoints[startPoint[0]][1]
            for endPoint in startPoint[1]:
                x2 = self.adjustedPoints[endPoint][0]
                y2 = self.adjustedPoints[endPoint][1]
                connectingLine = PathLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)
                # connectingLine.drawPath()
                self.scene().addItem(connectingLine)
                # QApplication.processEvents()
        self.scene().update()


    def findMinDistance(self,data, start):
        xStart, yStart = data[start]
        distances = []
        for item,[x,y] in data.items():
            if item != start and item != 0:
                distances.append(hypot(abs(xStart - x),abs(yStart-y)))
        output = self.mean(distances)-min(distances)
        if output < min(distances):
            output = min(distances)
        return output

    def mean(self,numbers):
        return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)


    def group(self,d, start,seen = []):
       x, y = d[start]
       r =[]
       print(start)
       dist = self.findMinDistance(d,start)
       print(dist)
       for a, [j, k] in d.items():
           if a != start and a not in seen and hypot(abs(x-j), abs(y-k)) <= dist:
               r.append(a)
       if not r:
         return {}
       result = {start:r}
       for i in r:
         result.update(self.group(d, i, seen+[start, *r]))
       return result


    def setPoints(self):
        self.setItems()
        # self.drawConnectingLines()
        self.setDragMode(self.ScrollHandDrag)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        for item in self.scene().items():
            item.findLineWidth(self._zoom)

        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0: # angleDelta is positive 120 zooming in and -120 going out
            factor = 1.25
            self._zoom += 1
        else:
            factor = 0.8
            self._zoom -= 1
        if self._zoom > 0:
            self.scale(factor, factor)
        elif self._zoom == 0:
            self.reset_fit()
        else:
            self._zoom = 0

    def hoverChange(self):
        self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

    def notHoverChange(self):
        self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            singleItem = self.itemAt(event.pos().x(), event.pos().y())
            if singleItem != None:
                if QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == Qt.ShiftModifier: # This will determine if the shift key is depressed
                    if singleItem.isSelected == True:
                        singleItem.setSelected(False)
                        singleItem.isSelected = False
                        self.selectedItems.remove(singleItem)
                elif singleItem.isSelected == False:
                    singleItem.setSelected(True)
                    singleItem.isSelected = True
                    self.selectedItems.append(singleItem)
            else:
                self.origin = event.pos()
                self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, QSize()))
                self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
                self.rubberBand.show()
                self.changeRubberBand = True
            return

        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            self.original_event = event
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(
                QEvent.MouseButtonPress,
                QPointF(event.pos()),
                Qt.LeftButton,
                event.buttons(),
                Qt.KeyboardModifiers(),
            )
            QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self, handmade_event)

        super(Viewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        point = event.pos()
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.changeRubberBand = False
            if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
                self.rubberBand.hide()
                rect = self.rubberBand.geometry()
                rect_scene = self.mapToScene(rect).boundingRect()
                selected = self.scene().items(rect_scene)
                if selected:
                    # print(selected)
                    for selectedPoints in selected:
                        if QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == Qt.ShiftModifier: # This will determine if the shift key is depressed
                            if selectedPoints.isSelected == True:
                                selectedPoints.setSelected(False)
                                selectedPoints.isSelected = False
                                self.selectedItems.remove(selectedPoints)
                        elif selectedPoints.isSelected == False: # if the shif key is not depressed and its not selected, then select it
                            selectedPoints.setSelected(True)
                            selectedPoints.isSelected = True
                            self.selectedItems.append(selectedPoints)
                    print( "".join("Item: %s\n" % child.name for child in self.selectedItems))
                else:
                    print(" Nothing\n")
                    for selected in self.selectedItems:
                        selected.setSelected(False)
                        selected.isSelected = False
                    self.selectedItems.clear()
                    QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)

        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(
                QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,
                QPointF(event.pos()),
                Qt.LeftButton,
                event.buttons(),
                Qt.KeyboardModifiers(),
            )
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self, handmade_event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.changeRubberBand:
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(
                QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized()
            )
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            QGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def reset_fit(self):
        r = self.scene().itemsBoundingRect()
        self.resetTransform()
        self.setSceneRect(r)
        self.fitInView(r, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self._zoom = 0
        self.scale(1, -1)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = Viewer(self)
        self.btnFindPath = QToolButton(self)
        self.btnFindPath.setText("Draw Path")
        self.btnFindPath.clicked.connect(self.autoDrawLines)

        VBlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnFindPath)
        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def autoDrawLines(self):
        self.viewer.drawConnectingLines()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawPath(x1,y1,x2,y2)` effectively draws a line from `scale*(x1, y1)` to `scale*(x2, y2)` in item coordinates where `scale = 250`. In `PathLine.__init__` you then move this line to `(x1, y1)` (in scene coordinates) and you scale it by a factor 1.5 which means that in scene coordinates the lines go from `(1.5*scale+1)*(x1,y1)` to `1.5*scale*(x2,y2)+(x1,y1)`.

However the circles and squares generated by `create_circle` and `create_square` are centered around `(0,0)` in item coordinates and moved to `(x1,y1)` in `Point.__init__`.

Therefore, to get the lines to match up with the circles and squares you should set scale to 1.0 in `drawPath`, keep the position of the line at (0,0) and its scale to 1.0 in `PathLine.__init__`. Also, you need to set an initial line with and line color to be able to see them, i.e.

```
def drawPath(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    path = QPainterPath()
    path.moveTo(x1,y1)
    path.lineTo(x2,y2)
    return path

class PathLine(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self,x1,y1,x2,y2):
        super(PathLine,self).__init__()
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        # self.name = name
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable,True)
        self.setPath(drawPath(x1,y1,x2,y2))
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.log = LogObject()
        pen = QPen(Qt.white)
        pen.setStyle(Qt.SolidLine)
        pen.setWidthF(4)
        self.setPen(pen)
        self.isSelected = False
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your explanation. So the lines were being drawn, but they were off somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, basically. Plus they were initially drawn in black (the default color), so even if they had been inside the visible area you wouldn't have been able to see them on the black background ;-)